# MIPS and bytes explanation

Tags: assembly, byte, mips

These 3 questions are the only ones I didn't understand in class.  My professor is horrible & isn't clear at all when explaining the material which is why I had to come here.  I have answers for some of them but I don't know if they're correct.  Thank you so much in advance, I greatly appreciate that you took the time to read.

1. Give the assembly instruction in order to:

a) Isolate Byte 1 of a word in $s0 using only logical shifts.

b)  Complement the lower 12 bits of register $t0 but leave all the other bits unchanged.  If possible, use immediate format instruction.  If it's not possible to use immediate format instruction, explain why and use mask a register instead.

c)  Mask the shift amount of an R-Format instruction and clear the rest of the bits.  If possible, use immediate format instruction.  If it's not possible to use immediate format instruction, explain why and use mask register instead.

---

2. This code is for question 2a

loop:
slt $t2, $t0, $t0

```
   bne $t2, $zero, loop

   j done
```

done:

a)  The address of bne is 400.  Give its target address.

---

3. Given the assembly instruction beq $t1, $t2, Next

a)  If the address of the instruction is 800bytes and Next is at target address 680 bytes.  What will be the value of the offset field of the instructions binary representation?  Give the offset value in decimal and in binary.

---

My answers:

1a.  sll $t0, $s0, 16
     srl $t1, $t0, 24

b.   xori (can't figure out the rest)

c.  andi $t0, $s1, 0x07c0

2a. 424           (400 + 4) + (4 * 3) = 416

b.

3a.  I think you have to do 800-680 but I don't know for sure.  What I do know is that the offset value has to be 16 bits when written in binary.

Comment: There are free MIPS simulators like SPIM and MARS which you could use to verify your answers.

Comment: I understand.  But I want know how to do it by hand instead of using a simulator.

Answer (score 0):

1a is wrong, if you don't shift the same amount it can't be correct. Shift 24 bits left to clear the top 24 bits then shift 24 bits right to return the low byte to its place.

1b would be a `xori 0xfff` however the 12 bit immediate in the instruction is sign extended automatically so that would actually mean `xori 0xffffffff` which is not what you want. That's why you need to use a mask register.

1c is correct

2a the `loop` is clearly just before the `bne` so the address must be `bne-4=396`.

3a yeah `800-680` but you need to account for the fact that the PC is already updated and the offset is encoded in words, so you need to divide by `4` giving `(800-680)/4-1=29`

Comment: I greatly appreciate your response.  For 1a, does it that mean it should be...  
sll $t0, $s0, 24
srl $t0, $s0, 24.  

For 3a, you said to divide by 4 but then you did 4-1, that would be 3.  I'm little lost on that part.

Comment: 1a yes except why do you use 2 different registers? 3a you know division takes precedence, right? That's dividing by 4, then subtracting 1 because the PC already points to the next instruction (next word).

Comment: For 1a, would it just be sll $t0, $s0, 24.  For 3a, Let's say If the address of the instruction is 320bytes and Next is at target address 550 bytes.  Would that be (550-320)/4-1 = 56.5?  I apologize for the constant questions.  Again, my teacher isn't great at explaining these things.

Comment: No idea why you introduce `$t0`. It should be `sll $s0, $s0, 24; srl $s0, $s0, 24`. You can't have an instruction at address `550` because that's not word aligned.

Comment: Gotcha, 3a is clear now.  My last question is this. If 1a said: Isolate Byte 3 or 4 (for example) of a word in $s0 using only logical shifts.  Would the answer still be sll $s0, $s0, 24; srl $s0, $s0, 24?

Comment: How could the answer be the same if you need a different byte? You shift left and right as much as needed to clear the extra bytes then shift the remaining byte back into position. Since for the lowest byte there is nothing to the right, we didn't need that shift. In the general case you would need 3 shifts.

Comment: So what would the answer be to isolate Byte 3 and Byte 4.  I'm so sorry to bother you like this.  If I see the answer, I'd understand it much better.

Comment: To isolate byte 4 (the most significant byte) you just need to zero the 3 least significant bytes so a right shift of 24 then a left shift of 24. To isolate byte 3, you need to clear the byte on the left, so left shift of 8, then need to clear the 3 bytes to the right, so right shift of 24, then you need to shift left 16 to get it back into its place.